# Doesn't have a constructer that take 0 arguments in C#

Tags: c#, constructor

I've got this error while I program in C#:
'BankSystem.Account' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

My classes are:

Firstly, the Account class:

```
 public abstract class Account : IAccount
{

    private static decimal minIncome = 0;
    private static int minAge = 18;

    private string name;
    private string address;
    private decimal age;
    private decimal balance;

    public Account(string inName, decimal inAge, decimal inBalance, string inAddress)
    {
        if (AccountAllowed(inBalance, inAge))
        {
            name = inName;
            address = inAddress;
            balance = inBalance;
            age = inAge;

            Console.WriteLine("We created the account. \nName is " + name + " \nThe address is: "
            + address + "\nThe balance is " + balance);

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("We cann't create the account. Please check the balance and age!");
        }
    }

    //public CustomerAccount(string newName, decimal initialBalance)

    public Account(string inName, decimal initialBalance)
    {
    }
```

Secondly, The CustomerAccount class:

```
 public class CustomerAccount : Account
{
    private decimal balance = 0;
    private string name;

    public CustomerAccount(string newName, decimal initialBalance)
    {
        name = newName;
        balance = initialBalance;
    }

    public CustomerAccount(string inName, decimal inAge, decimal inBalance, string inAddress)
        : base(inName, inAge)
    {

        // name = inName;
        //age = inAge;
    }

    public CustomerAccount(string inName, decimal inAge)
        : base(inName, inAge)
    {

        // name = inName;
        //age = inAge;
    } ......
```

Comment: You are going to need to show us more code than that. The error sounds like you are trying to call one of the functions without passing anything through to it.

Comment: The error message contains the answer.

Comment: You aren't at RBS are you? ;-) If you are invoking the 2 parameter constructor on CustomerAccount, as it derives from account, it will attempt to call base(). As you don't have a parameterless constructor on the base, Account, your code fails.

Answer (score 7):

Because you have defined constructors with parameters in your class, you will not get the default constructor by default.

Your account class has defined constructors:

```
public Account(string inName, decimal inAge, decimal inBalance, string inAddress)
public Account(string inName, decimal initialBalance)
```

you may define a default constructor like.

```
public Account() 
{
}
```

The error you are getting is because, your below constructor for `CustomerAccount` is implicitly calling a default constructor for the Account base class, as you have not specified any other base constructor e.g. `:base(arg1,arg2);`

```
 public CustomerAccount(string newName, decimal initialBalance)
    {
        name = newName;
        balance = initialBalance;
    }
```

The above is same as:

```
 public CustomerAccount(string newName, decimal initialBalance) : base()
```

Comment: But I doesn't use the default constructor in my code! How it comes?

Comment: @AliEssa Actually, your line `public CustomerAccount(string newName, decimal initialBalance)` implicitly calls the default base constructor since, as Habib.OSU points out, you did not call a specific base constructor.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx : "In a derived class, if a base-class constructor is not called explicitly by using the base keyword, the default constructor, if there is one, is called implicitly."

Answer (score 7):

You need to 'chain' to the base constructor here too:

```
public CustomerAccount(string newName, decimal initialBalance)
    : base(newName, 0)    // something like this
{
    name = newName;
    balance = initialBalance;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple. Your `Account` class doesn't contain a contructor with Zero arguments e.g.

```
public Account()
{

}
```

The answer is in the error message.

When you create a new instance of the `Account` class pass in the correct parameters e.g.

`Account account = new Account("John Smith", 20.00);`

Or create a constructor that takes zero arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing  your `Account` class like this

```
new Account();
```

but should do

```
new Account("name", ...);
```

according to your constructor definition.